# Read file of many lower triangular matrices and convert to pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, parsing, matrix, import

I have a file with thousand of lower triangular matrices (one under the other):

```
1|Gene1_PRT1                
2|Gene2_PRT1    0           
2|Gene3_PRT1    0   0       
1|Gene7_PRT1    1.4287  1.4287  1.5293  
2|Gene9_PRT1    1.4428  1.4428  1.5293  0

2|Gene90_PRT1       
1|Gene60_PRT1   1.6242  
2|Gene26454_PRT1    -1  -1
```

And I need a list/table with the pairwise (gene) name on the left and values (where the diagonal, 0 comparison with itself are removed).
Like:

```
2|Gene68760_PRT1    1|Gene32540_PRT1    0
2|Gene99122_PRT1    1|Gene32540_PRT1    0
1|Gene2362_PRT1     1|Gene32540_PRT1    1.4287
2|Gene63993_PRT1    1|Gene32540_PRT1    1.4428
2|Gene99122_PRT1    2|Gene68760_PRT1    0
1|Gene2362_PRT1     2|Gene68760_PRT1    1.4287
2|Gene63993_PRT1    2|Gene68760_PRT1    1.4428
1|Gene2362_PRT1     2|Gene99122_PRT1    1.5293
2|Gene63993_PRT1    2|Gene99122_PRT1    1.5293
2|Gene63993_PRT1    1|Gene2362_PRT1     0
```

I tried a little bit with, simple grep etc. function, and I have a list of values but not the pairwise name on the left. I'm a newbie in (bio)informatics, trying to learn...

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible exemple of what you've already got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is fast enough:

```
#read the data
dat <- readLines(textConnection("1|Gene1_PRT1                
2|Gene2_PRT1    0           
2|Gene3_PRT1    0   0       
1|Gene7_PRT1    1.4287  1.4287  1.5293  
2|Gene9_PRT1    1.4428  1.4428  1.5293  0

2|Gene90_PRT1       
1|Gene60_PRT1   1.6242  
2|Gene26454_PRT1    -1  -1"))

#split the data using the fact that there are empty rows
dat <- split(dat[dat!=""],cumsum(dat=="")[dat!=""])

#split the rows
dat <- lapply(dat,strsplit,split=" +")

#create matrices with lower triangles and melt them
library(reshape2)    
dat <- lapply(dat,function(x) {
  mat <- matrix(ncol=length(x),nrow=length(x))
  nam <- do.call(c,lapply(x,function(y) y[1]))
  rownames(mat) <- nam
  colnames(mat) <- nam

  mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- do.call(c,lapply(x,function(y) as.numeric(y[-1])))
  na.omit(melt(t(mat)))
})

#rbind everything together
do.call(rbind,dat)


#                  Var1          Var2   value
# 0.2      2|Gene2_PRT1  1|Gene1_PRT1  0.0000
# 0.3      2|Gene3_PRT1  1|Gene1_PRT1  0.0000
# 0.4      1|Gene7_PRT1  1|Gene1_PRT1  1.4287
# 0.5      2|Gene9_PRT1  1|Gene1_PRT1  1.4428
# 0.8      2|Gene3_PRT1  2|Gene2_PRT1  0.0000
# 0.9      1|Gene7_PRT1  2|Gene2_PRT1  1.4287
# 0.10     2|Gene9_PRT1  2|Gene2_PRT1  1.4428
# 0.14     1|Gene7_PRT1  2|Gene3_PRT1  1.5293
# 0.15     2|Gene9_PRT1  2|Gene3_PRT1  1.5293
# 0.20     2|Gene9_PRT1  1|Gene7_PRT1  0.0000
# 1.2     1|Gene60_PRT1 2|Gene90_PRT1  1.6242
# 1.3  2|Gene26454_PRT1 2|Gene90_PRT1 -1.0000
# 1.6  2|Gene26454_PRT1 1|Gene60_PRT1 -1.0000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks great, but it do not parse correctly the matrices! E.g. in your output e.g. line 3 (# 0.4      1|Gene7_PRT1  1|Gene1_PRT1  0.0000) the value should be 1.4287 according to the matrix...If you have any idea... Otherwise thank you very much for the code, I will try to play around with it...

Comment: @lola The recommended way to express your gratitude on StackOverflow is to vote on an answer (see the arrows at the upper left side of each post) and to click the check mark to indicate that the question has been answered to your satisfaction. See [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for details.